# Strange Photoshop Text tool options

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I've been learning Photoshop, used the Text tool many times but today I came across some options which I've never seen before. Can someone explain what they are for, and how to turn them on/off? 
[image]

Comment: The options appear when you highlight a letter in a font which has alternate glyphs available. I honestly don't know if there's a way to switch off this feature. Perhaps have a look in the preferences?

Comment: Thanks, if this can be useful I'll keep it

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck (disable) the `Preferences → Type → Enable type layer glyph alternates` feature.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if it's useful I'll keep it, strange thing is that in my case this option is available just under "o" letters. Do you know why and where can i customize it?

Comment: @rp_photos - it only shows up when you have highlighted a letter which has an alternate glyph in the specific font you have selected.  So, it actually depends on the font. Some fonts have no alternates, and some have many.

Comment: @Billy Kerr - Ok, thanks a lot.